# For a REST stateless service layer in web API .net core 2+, which lifetime is preferred Transient or Singleton?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In a 3 tier web API .net core REST application. We are not going to maintain state in Service layers.

Assuming my code is clearly constructed in way not relying on a state. Which object creation lifetime is preferred.

**Transient or Singleton.**

If transient (why would i need to create every time, though i am not relying on any state).

Why not singleton?

Which is highly performant ?

Comment: depends on the actual instance. is it a database connection? is it expensive to create?

Comment: No, it is not expensive to create, lightweight only.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your service instantiation cost. for example, DbContent cost is not equal with a simple application service. but a Transient lifetime works best for lightweight, stateless services.